# Low quality angular electron screenshot

Tags: angular, image, electron, desktop-application, screen-capture

I need to take a screenshot so show or save and I'm trying like this:

```
this._electronService.desktopCapturer.getSources({types: ['screen']}).then(async sources => {
  this.image = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(sources[0].thumbnail.toDataURL());
});
```

If I do this, I get a reduced image where I can't see anything. I attach a sample of a capture that I get. If I set a bigger width or height, the image is pixeled.

[image: Screenshot]

Futhermore, I need to save this img and I tried this:

```
writeContents(content, fileName, contentType) {
    let a = document.createElement('a');
    let file = new Blob([content], {type: contentType});
    a.href = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    a.download = fileName;
    a.click();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is simple, just add a new option indicating the size of the capture, by default it is small and that's why it looks like this. An example:

```
this._electronService.desktopCapturer.getSources(
{
    types: ['screen'],
    thumbnailSize: {
        height: 720,
        width: 1000
    }
}).then(async sources => {
  this.image = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(sources[0].thumbnail.toDataURL());
});
```

Comment: How do we get the actual size of the display area being captured in the screen. I'm setting random size in height and width and the image does not look correct.